# Python 3.4.4 How to verify if a string is only made of 0 and 1

Tags: python

I'm doing a binary to decimal converter in python 3.4.4 and it's pretty much finished except for the fact that I would like to check that the binary number entered by the user is indeed a binary number (check if the string is only made of o and 1) but I'm unsure what to do.

here's the program:

```
binary=input("Enter a binary number") 
bit=len(binary)
result=0
power=0
while bit>0:
    result=result+int(binary[bit-1])*2**power
    bit=bit-1
    power=power+1
print(binary, " in decimal is equal to ", result, sep="")
```

hopefully someone can help me <3

Comment: thank you all for helping, it works
(some of the solutions looked too complex and i didn't use them, should have precised i wasn't really an expert xD)

Answer (score 6):

Follow the [EAFP approach](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp), try to convert it to decimal via [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) and handle the `ValueError`:

```
try:
    int(binary, 2)
    is_binary = True
except ValueError:
    is_binary = False
```

Comment: At which point they may as well add `return` and be done with it.

Answer (score 3):

If you *must* avoid using `int(binary, 2)` and handle the exception, you could use the [`all()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
all(c in '01' for c in binary)
```

`all()` with a generator expression will bail out early and return `False` when a non-binary digit is found.

If you are already looping over all characters *anyway* you could just raise an exception in your loop:

```
binary=input("Enter a binary number") 
bit=len(binary)
result=0
power=0
try:
    while bit>0:
        if binary[bit-1] not in '01':
            raise ValueError('Not a binary string: %s' % binary)
        result=result+int(binary[bit-1])*2**power
        bit=bit-1
        power=power+1
except ValueError:
    print('%s is not a binary string')
else:
    print(binary, " in decimal is equal to ", result, sep="")
```

Rather than use an index, your code could just loop over the reverse of the string, using numbers generated by [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) as the power:

```
binary = input("Enter a binary number") 
result = 0
try:
    for power, bit in enumerate(reversed(binary)):
        if bit not in '01':
            raise ValueError('Not a binary string: %s' % binary)
        result += int(bit) * 2 ** power
except ValueError:
    print('%s is not a binary string')
else:
    print(binary, " in decimal is equal to ", result, sep="")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `all()`

```
 all(x in '10' for x in binary_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `all(x in "01" for x in binary)`.

Answer (score 0):

Following is for 2.7.9, just look for a 3.4.4 parallel:

```
import re

binary = raw_input("enter binary number")
if re.match("^[01]*$", binary):
    print "ok"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the sum of  occurrences of '0' and '1' is equal to the length of the string.

```
 binary.count('0') + binary.count('1') == len(binary)
```

Comment: A downvote without an explanation seems a little cowardly to me and it certainly doesn't help the one who posted the answer. What's more, this solution appears to also work.

Comment: @MattCremeens: it may work, but is rather inefficient; `str.count()` traverses the string in full, so this does two full scans. *All* other solutions presented here bail out early; i.e. they'll report failure the moment the first invalid character is detected while scanning.

Comment: Then whoever downvoted should have stated as such so that the poster can learn from it. Downvoting without explanation does nothing more than lower the self-esteem and confidence of the one who posted. And, honestly, it's tough for me to understand downvoting a post that works, even if it is less efficient than the other posts. I could see upvoting all posts other than this one, maybe. But his code has the benefit of being easy to understand as often less-efficient code can be. That is worth at least something.

Comment: my answer was made with the assumption that the asker is a student doing a homework or a beginner, who can not use or don't understand what is an exception, regular expression, etc.
So I offer a simply and intuitive  solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose checking the input string for correctness is best done with regular expressions. The code that would help you is the following:

```
import re

binary = input("Enter a binary number") 
len_bin = len(binary)
result = 0
if re.search("^[0-1]+$", binary) is not None:
    for position in range(len_bin):
        result += int(binary[position]) * 2 ** (len_bin - position - 1)

    print(binary + " in decimal is equal to " + str(result))
else:
    print("The input is not a binary number")
```

The regular expression determines whether the binary number only contains zeros and ones. Also, I took the opportunity to shorten the code a bit, using `result += ...`, which is equal to `result = result + ...`.